# Looking for Medical (FDA) approved IOC-Container

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, medical

I am looking for an IOC-Container that is approved to be used in medical products without the urge to verify it within the project.

Any ideas/suggestions/ressources?

BR

Comment: I am not sure there would be *any* that's been "approved". You can always write a small one by yourself or use the one that is the most mature and has extensive Unit-tests.

Comment: Writing one by myself is ofc an option, but I'm not that much into "not invtented here", so I'd prefer a steady solution.

Comment: I don't think the FDA would bother to "approve" something that has nothing to do with its field of work...

Comment: Most likely this will be closed as too localized. I cannot see what is the difference between medical software and other software, assuming that you are not going to write life-critical software (if you are then it's a whole different ball game).

Comment: You might want to post this to http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/

Comment: healthcareit.stackexchange.com is less about software developement. @Thomas you can approve pretty much anything at the FDA, especially software component vendors (like infragistics, etc) tend to do this as an additional benefit for using their product.

Comment: @Jaster: FDA approves medical devices, that can be standalone software, but not software components. Infragistics may be used in FDA-approved software, but they didn't approve the component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Framework can be approved pretty easy since it offers full Unit Test converage out of the box.